# Couldn't translate a subquery in entity framework core

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

i have this subquery

```
select * from MetaInfo where MetaInfoParentId = (select id from MetaInfo where KeyName='CATEGORIA' and Value = 'PAISES')
```

i'm trying to rewrite this in entity framework core but there is this error:

```
return await _appDbcontext.MetaInfo.Where(m => m.Id == _appDbcontext.MetaInfo
                                           .Where(b => b.KeyName.Equals("CATEGORIA") && b.Value.Equals(category)
                                           ).Select(b => b.Id).ToListAsync());
```

*cs0019 operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Guid' and 'Task<List>'*

Comment: Try `return await _appDbcontext.MetaInfo.Where(m => _appDbcontext.MetaInfo.Where(b => b.KeyName.Equals("CATEGORIA") && b.Value.Equals(category).Select(b => b.Id).Contains(m.Id)).ToLIstAsync();`

Answer (score 4):

As error shows

> cs0019 operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Guid' and
> 'Task'

which means you are trying to compare `Guid` with `Task<List<Guid>>` which is not possible.

You can achieve this by using `.Contains` or `.Any` function.

**1st Approach:** Using `.Contains` function

```
return await _appDbcontext.MetaInfo
      .Where(m => _appDbcontext.MetaInfo
            .Where(b => b.KeyName.Equals("CATEGORIA") 
                     && b.Value.Equals(category))
            .Select(b => b.Id).Contains(m.Id))
      .ToListAsync();
```

**2nd Approach:** Using `.Any` function.

```
return await _appDbcontext.MetaInfo
             .Where(m => _appDbcontext.MetaInfo
                    .Any(b => b.KeyName.Equals("CATEGORIA")
                     && b.Value.Equals(category) && b.Id=m.Id))
             .ToListAsync();
```

For more information about `.Contains` please read [this from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-6.0)

For more information about `.Any` please read [this from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0)

Comment: You are missing something, that makes the result awaitable like `ToListAsync()`

Comment: Yup, thanks for mentioning it, actually it's easy to forget in StackOverflow editor. I have updated my Answer.